# tables messes up when printing

Tags: css, printing

I'm struggling with printing tables. I have a system where I show/hide diffrent location when user clicks on them.

This is some html-code (from firebug)

[image]

Each div with class location-info contains a table with courses and their pupils and some other info. Notice that the first .location-info div has display set to none (because user has hidden it when clicked). When the code looks like above and I do a preview it looks like this (**NOT ALL NAMES** are shown and somehow the tables messes up for some reason):

[image]

BUT when **both** .location-info divs are set to display:block (when the user clicks and show both locations), then it looks like this: (**ALL names are shown**)

[image]

Here is the css used for printing:

```
@media print {
    #adminmenuback {display:none;}
    #adminmenuwrap {display:none;}
    .screen-reader-shortcut {display:none;}
    #wpadminbar {display:none;}
    .update-nag {display:none;}
    #wpfooter {display:none;}
    #wpbody {width:100%;}
    #wpcontent {margin:2em;}
    #wpbody-content {padding-bottom:0;}
    .change-reserver_user {display:none;}
    .print-link {display:none;}
    .admin-email-links {display:none;}
    .toggle-minus-plus-admin {display:none;}
    h3.location {display:block;}
    #screen-meta {display:none;}
    .screen-only {display:none;}
    #course-header {display:none;}
    .print-only {display:inline-block;}     
    #user-list .location-info.selected-for-print .form-table.courses {border:10px solid red;page-break-after: always;}
}
```

**I obviously want it to show all names even if just one .location-info is visible. How do I achieve that? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Not living up to your username eh?? :-) Sorry just had to say it

Comment: @Rottingham - my username is not so seriously ment :-)

Comment: @castis, thanks for editing my code. Of course it should not be php-tag.